# Is it possible to use geojson together with the flutter_map lib?

Tags: flutter, geojson, fluttermap

I need to implement something similar to the photo through a geojson. This data is dynamic and is coming from the server. I've done some research but haven't found anything that can help me. Has anyone managed to implement this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no, and depends a bit when you say its dynamic (i.e it comes from the server, but does it change within x hours ?

Anyway, I'm doing a plugin at https://github.com/ibrierley/geojson_vector_slicer which handles fast geojson and things like that, but is designed for more static geojson (or at least not frequently changing geojson). It's very much in alpha, but it may help and I'll help with anyone who wants to try it.

Other solution is to decode the geojson as normal json, and build up lists of polylines from lineStrings, polygons from polygons, and markers from points. Then just supply these to your flutter_map children/layers.

Comment: The structure does not change. What changes are the values ​​of the lines. This change occurs when the user presses a refresh button.

Comment: That may be ok if its intermittent, it would just need to rebuild the index every time which may take a few secs depending on size. Otherwise you need to redecode the geojson anyway, but there are some flutter packages to help with that.